# I cannot search users via user nicename

Tags: wp-query

I use the following to build a users drop-down box:

```
echo'<select name="user">';
echo'<option value="0">' . __('ALL', 'wpzoom') . '</option>';
foreach( $users as $user ){
    echo '<option value="'.$user->data->user_nicename.'">'.$user->data->display_name.'</option>';
}
echo'</select>';
```

but the WP_Query I use to trap the result returns empty resultset:

```
$user = $_GET["user"];

$args = array(                   
 'order' => 'DESC',                                       
 'orderby' => 'date',
 'posts_per_page'=> 10,
 'paged' => $paged
);

if ( '0' != $user ) {
    $args['author_name'] = $user;
 }

$lala = new WP_Query($args);
```

This is strange because WP_Query documentation says this is correct.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You should be using `$_GET` or `$_POST` when you process the form. I don't see either.

Comment: I edited the question and added the $_GET command which exists in my code.
Thank you

Comment: Are there `form` tags around your `select`?

Comment: Yes, there are. The form submission is performed OK.

Comment: If passed a valid user nicename, that code does work. I tested it.

Comment: Post more code details, actually is impossible to say what's wrong, because there's nothing wrong on the posted code. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you, you are right.
I use co-authors plus plugin to attach multiple authors to the post. Querying authors is thus problematic.
Any experience on this?